# Can Derby handle scalar subqueries in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, join, derby, scalar

I'm having trouble getting my query working.  Could someone cast an experienced eye on it please?  The table structure is simple (2 one-to-many relationships).  The query is trying to work out for each sign, how many contributions there are at each unique "PositionLocation".

```
Sign <- Signifier (f_key sign_oid) <- Contribution (f_key signifier_oid)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: An ON clause associated with a JOIN operator is not valid.
SQLState:  42972
ErrorCode: -1
```

My query is:

```
select s.NAME, c.POSITIONLOCATION, count(*) as num_per_locn,
(
    select count(*) from APP.CONTRIBUTION c2
    inner join APP.SIGNIFIER si2 on si2.OID = c2.SIGNIFIER_OID
    inner join APP.SIGN s2 on s2.OID = si2.SIGN_OID
    and  s2.OID = s.OID
) as num_per_sign
from APP.CONTRIBUTION c
inner join APP.SIGNIFIER si on si.OID = c.SIGNIFIER_OID
inner join APP.SIGN s on s.OID = si.SIGN_OID
group by s.NAME, c.POSITIONLOCATION
```

Comment: BTW - Obviously the scalar join to SIGN s2 is superfluous, and could just use the SIGNIFIER table foreign key: si2.SIGN_OID = s.OID

Comment: Can you provide sql fiddle ?